# Unable to put assets folder in flask application

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a flask app. i have assets folder containing files, fonts, images and javascript where should I put them? i put index.html in templates. I have tried them putting in static folder but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest organizing your directory structure as such:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    static/
    templates/
    views/
    models.py
run.py
```

Then you can organize your static folder based on personal preference. For example, something such as:

```
static/
    css/
        lib/
            bootstrap.css
        style.css
        home.css
        admin.css
    js/
        lib/
            jquery.js
        home.js
        admin.js
    img/
        logo.svg
        favicon.ico
```

By default *flask will look for static content in the static folder relative to where the application is initialized and started.* For more info about static files check out this [link](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html)

Hopefully that helps!